# Google maps radius circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Im currently developing an web application which includes google maps. Im developing using Jquery and a lib called GMAP3. You can take a look here if you want. http://gmap3.net/
I've created a driving direction function and also an radius circle function. Im using an javascript menu to run the functions. You can for example place the orgin position with right clicking on that position and chose place orgin position using a menu. That part works correctly. A marker is added to that position and also a circle which centers from that position. BUT, if im moving the driving direction destination marker the circle still stays on its place. I do really need some help with this. Thanks.

**Javascript code:**

```
  /**************************************************
   *                      Menu
   **************************************************/

  function Menu($div){
    var that = this, 
        ts = null;

    this.$div = $div;
    this.items = [];

    // create an item using a new closure 
    this.create = function(item){
      var $item = $('<div class="item '+item.cl+'">'+item.label+'</div>');
      $item
        // bind click on item
        .click(function(){
          if (typeof(item.fnc) === 'function'){
            item.fnc.apply($(this), []);
          }
        })
        // manage mouse over coloration
        .hover(
          function(){$(this).addClass('hover');},
          function(){$(this).removeClass('hover');}
        );
      return $item;
    };
    this.clearTs = function(){
      if (ts){
        clearTimeout(ts);
        ts = null;
      }
    };
    this.initTs = function(t){
      ts = setTimeout(function(){that.close()}, t);
    };
  }

  // add item
  Menu.prototype.add = function(label, cl, fnc){
    this.items.push({
      label:label,
      fnc:fnc,
      cl:cl
    });
  }

  // close previous and open a new menu 
  Menu.prototype.open = function(event){
    this.close();
    var k,
        that = this,
        offset = {
          x:0, 
          y:0
        },
        $menu = $('<div id="menu"></div>');

    // add items in menu
    for(k in this.items){
      $menu.append(this.create(this.items[k]));
    }

    // manage auto-close menu on mouse hover / out
    $menu.hover(
      function(){that.clearTs();},
      function(){that.initTs(3000);}
    );

    // change the offset to get the menu visible (#menu width & height must be defined in CSS to use this simple code)
    if ( event.pixel.y + $menu.height() > this.$div.height()){
      offset.y = -$menu.height();
    }
    if ( event.pixel.x + $menu.width() > this.$div.width()){
      offset.x = -$menu.width();
    }

    // use menu as overlay
    this.$div.gmap3({
      action:'addOverlay',
      latLng: event.latLng,
      content: $menu,
      offset: offset
    });

    // start auto-close
    this.initTs(5000);
  }

  // close the menu
  Menu.prototype.close = function(){
    this.clearTs();
    this.$div.gmap3({action:'clear', name:'overlay'});
  }


  /**************************************************
   *                      Main
   **************************************************/

  $(function(){

    var $map = $('#googleMap'), 
        menu = new Menu($map),

        current,  // current click event (used to save as start / end position)
        m1,       // marker "from"
        m2,       // marker "to"
        center = [48.85861640881589, 2.3459243774414062];

    // update marker
    function updateMarker(marker, isM1){
      if (isM1){
        m1 = marker;
      } else {
        m2 = marker;
      }
      updateDirections();
    }

    function Startdistancewidget()
    {          
            $map.gmap3({
            action: 'addCircle',
            circle:{
            options:{
            center: current.latLng,
            radius : 75000,
            fillColor : "Green",
            strokeColor : "White"   
        }
    }
})
    }

    function Finishdistancewidget()
    {          
            $map.gmap3({
            action: 'addCircle',
            circle:{
            options:{
            center: current.latLng,
            radius : 75000,
            fillColor : "Red",
            strokeColor : "White"   
        }
    }
})
    }



    // add marker and manage which one it is (A, B)
    function addMarker(isM1){
      // clear previous marker if set
      var clear = {action:'clear', name:'marker', tag:''};
      if (isM1 && m1) {
        clear.tag = 'from';
        $map.gmap3(clear);
      } else if (!isM1 && m2){
        clear.tag = 'to';
        $map.gmap3(clear);
      }
      // add marker and store it
      $map.gmap3({
        action:'addMarker',
        latLng:current.latLng,
        options:{
          draggable:true,
          icon:new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/icon_big_' + (isM1 ? 'start' : 'stop') + '.png')
        },
        tag: (isM1 ? 'from' : 'to'),
        events: {
          dragend: function(marker){
            updateMarker(marker, isM1);
          }
        },
        callback: function(marker){
          updateMarker(marker, isM1);
        }
      });

    }

    // function called to update direction is m1 and m2 are set
    function updateDirections(){
      if (!(m1 && m2)){
        return;
      }
      $map.gmap3({
        action:'getRoute',
        options:{
          origin:m1.getPosition(),
          destination:m2.getPosition(),
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        callback: function(results){
          if (!results) return;
          $map.gmap3({ action: 'setDirections', directions:results});
        }
      });
    }

    // MENU : ITEM 1
    menu.add('Allign start position here', 'itemA', 
      function(){
        menu.close();
        addMarker(true);
        Startdistancewidget();
      });

    // MENU : ITEM 2
    menu.add('Allign checkpoint position here', 'itemB', 
      function(){
        menu.close();
        addMarker(false);
      })

    // MENU : ITEM 3
    menu.add('Allign finish position here', 'itemC separator', 
      function(){
        menu.close();
        addMarker(false);
        Finishdistancewidget();
      })

    // MENU : ITEM 4
    menu.add('Zoom in', 'zoomIn', 
      function(){
        var map = $map.gmap3('get');
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        menu.close();
      });

    // MENU : ITEM 5
    menu.add('Zoom out', 'zoomOut',
      function(){
        var map = $map.gmap3('get');
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        menu.close();
      });

    // MENU : ITEM 6
    menu.add('Center here', 'centerHere', 
      function(){
          $map.gmap3('get').setCenter(current.latLng);
          menu.close();
      });

    // INITIALIZE GOOGLE MAP
    $map.gmap3(
      { action: 'init',
        options:{
          center:center,
          zoom: 5
        },
        events:{
          rightclick:function(map, event){
            current = event;
            menu.open(current);
          },
          click: function(){
            menu.close();
          },
          dragstart: function(){
            menu.close();
          },
          zoom_changed: function(){
            menu.close();
          }
        }
      },
      // add direction renderer to configure options (else, automatically created with default options)
      { action:'addDirectionsRenderer',
        preserveViewport: true,
        markerOptions:{
          visible: false
        }
      },
      // add a direction panel
      { action:'setDirectionsPanel',
        id : 'directions'
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what would be the syntax for that in gmap3 plugin but you have to bind circle to your marker if you want it to be repositioned if marker is dragged. In google API it is

```
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

I am doing almost the same thing right now.